# How to convert mysql query to laravel query builder?

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel

I have 2 tables and in first comments and article id, in second article title, id , category of article. I want has a title of article which has the most comments.

```
SELECT comments.article_id, news.title, news.category_id,
    COUNT(comments.id) as counts 
  FROM comments 
  JOIN news ON news.id = comments.article_id 
  GROUP BY(article_id) 
  ORDER BY counts DESC 
  LIMIT 3
```

I tried this:

```
  $articles = DB::table('comments')
        ->join('news', 'news.id', '=', ' comments.article_id')
        ->select(comments.article_id', 'news.title', ' news.category_id')
        ->count('comments.id')
        ->groupBy('article_id')
        ->orderBy(DB::raw('count(comments.id)', 'desc')
        ->limit(3)
        ->get();
```

But had:

```
Call to a member function groupBy() on integer
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a "finisher", which means `->count('comments.id')` does not return an instance of `QueryBuilder` anymore but a regular type (`integer`).

As `integers` in PHP are not classes, you are trying to perform a method on an non-class, which led to display this error message.

You surely know others finishers like `->sum()`, `->all()`, `->get()`, ...

Just remove your line `->count('comments.id')` and you will be good to go:

```
$articles = DB::table('comments')
  ->join('news', 'news.id', '=', ' comments.article_id')
  ->select('comments.article_id', 'news.title', ' news.category_id')
  ->groupBy('article_id')
  ->orderBy(DB::raw('count(comments.id)', 'desc')
  ->limit(3)
  ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DB::table('comments')
->join('news', 'news.id', '=', ' comments.article_id')
->selectRaw('comments.article_id', 'news.title', ' news.category_id', 'count(comments.id) as countsxyz')
->groupBy('article_id')
->orderBy(DB::raw('countsxyz'), 'desc')
->limit(3)
->get();
```

try this and let me know if you still face any issue.

Comment: "selectRaw() must be of the type array, string given "             again error